# How to return proper JSON in JAVA

Tags: java, json, spring

```
 private List<String> itemsInCart = new ArrayList<>();
 private List<String> itemObjectsInCart = new ArrayList<>();

@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping(value = "/cartitems")
public List<String> getItemsInCart(@RequestParam("buyerId") Integer buyerId) {
    if (cartRepository.findByBuyerIdAndIsCompleted(buyerId, false) != null){
        return getItemObjects(cartRepository.findByBuyerIdAndIsCompleted(buyerId, false).getItemsInCart());
    } else {
        return itemsInCart;
    }
}

public List<String> getItemObjects(List<String> itemsInCart){
    for (String item: itemsInCart) {
        String uri = "http://192.168.160.182:8762/item-service/items/" + item;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
        if(itemObjectsInCart.contains(result)){
            return itemObjectsInCart;
        } else {
            itemObjectsInCart.add(result);
        }
    }
return itemObjectsInCart;
}
```

Hi guys! My code above returns a JSON in this format:

```
["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Stick\",\"description\":\"A stick\",\"price\":100,\"available\":true,\"img\":\"https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/tokipona/images/a/aa/Stick.png/revision/latest?cb=20171120043817\",\"uploadDate\":\"2019-01-16\",\"sellerId\":1}"]
```

But I would like it whithout backslashes. Do you have any idea how could I convert it to a proper JSON array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can you use @RestController annotation and response will be returned as json.

Comment: What you're returning is a list of json strings. You'd either have to return _one_ string that contains the json or let the controller do that for you but in the latter case you must not convert your data to json yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `JSONObject` to map to JSON and don't read `String` directly. Create new POJO class for the response and let `RestTemplate` do the work. Internally Spring will use suitable converter to map the objects:

```
public class Item {
  int id;
  String name;
  String description;
  // other fields
  // getters and setters
}

Item result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Item.class);
```

Your controller method should also return `Item` and not `String`:

```
@GetMapping"/cartitems")
public List<Item> getItemsInCart(@RequestParam("buyerId") Integer buyerId) { 
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ResponseBody` to your request handler method or annotate your controller as `@RestController`.

Make sure you have `jackson` converter on your classpath. You can follow this tutorial - https://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-rest-example-tutorial-spring-restful-web-services